# FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 2, character 1) in flutter

Tags: sql, flutter, dart, xampp

```
void validateUserEmail() async {
    try {
      var res = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(API.validateEmail),
        body: {'user_email': emailController.text.trim()},
      );

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        var resBodyOfValidateEmail = jsonDecode(res.body);
        if (resBodyOfValidateEmail['emailFound'] == true) {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "Email is already in someone else use. Try another email");
        } else {
          //register  & save new record to database
          registerAndSaveUserRecord();
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e.toString());
    }
  }
```

I want the email to be checked so that duplicate emails are not registered.
Until it works (if (res.statusCode == 200)), then it quickly reaches catch (e)

Error:

> D/EGL_emulation(19014): app_time_stats: avg=54603.01ms min=16.04ms max=381957.19ms count=7
> I/flutter (19014): FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 2, character 1)
> I/flutter (19014): Connected successfully{"emailFound":true}

Comment: Is the body of the response from the server valid json that can be decoded?